# TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined

Tags: javascript, npm, discord, discord.js

Hello I have a big (kinda) trouble with my `play.js` for my discord bot. could you try to help me?

```
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "play",
    aliases: ["p", "playmusic"],
    description: "Plays your song!",
    usage: "[<put link in>]",
    run: async (client, message, args, ops) => {
        var voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;



    if (!message.member.voiceChannel){

        return message.reply("**Please join a voice chat to use this command**");

    }

    else if (!voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.guild.member(client.user)).has("CONNECT")) {

        return message.reply("Sorry I can't join that VC try a diffrent VC and make sure i have the connect permission if you need any help contact my owner").catch(console.error);

    }

    else if (voiceChannel.full && !voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.guild.member(client.user)).has('MOVE_MEMBERS')) {

        return message.channel.send("Sorry I can't join a full VC try joining a diffrent VC").catch(console.error);

    }



    if (!args[0])

        return message.reply("Sorry you need to send a url");



    let validate = await ytdl.validateURL(args[0]);

    if (!validate) {

        let commandFile = require('./search.js');

        return commandFile.run(client, message, args, ops)

    }



    let info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);



    let data = ops.active.get(message.guild.id) || {};



    if (!data.connection) data.connection = await message.member.voiceChannel.join();

    if (!data.queue) data.queue = [];

    data.guildID = message.guild.id

    data.queue.push({

        songTitle: info.title,

        requester: message.author.username,

        url: args[0],

        announceChannel: message.channel.id,

        thumbnail: info.thumbnail_url,

        timestamp: info.published,

    });



    if (!data.dispatcher) play(client, ops, data);

    else 

    {

        let qembed = new discord.RichEmbed()

        .setTitle(`Song Added: ${info.title}`)

        .setAuthor(`Song Requested by: ${message.author.username}`)

        .setColor("RANDOM")

        .setThumbnail(`${info.thumbnail_url}`)

        .setTimestamp(info.timestamp)

        .addField('Video Link', `${info.video_url}`)



        message.channel.send(qembed);

    }



    ops.active.set(message.guild.id, data);


    async function play(client, ops, data, connection, message) {

        let playembed = new discord.RichEmbed()

            .setTitle(`Now Playing: ${data.queue[0].songTitle}`)

            .setAuthor(`Song Requested by: ${data.queue[0].requester}`)

            .setColor("RANDOM")

            .setThumbnail(`${data.queue[0].thumbnail}`)

            .setTimestamp(data.queue[0].timestamp)

            let commandFile = require('./search.js');

            if (commandFile){playembed.addField('Video Link', `https://www.youtube.com${data.queue[0].url}`)}

            else if (!commandFile){playembed.addField('Video Link', `${data.queue[0].url}`)}

            client.channels.get(data.queue[0].announceChannel).send(playembed);

            data.dispatcher = await data.connection.playStream(ytdl(data.queue[0].url, { filter: 'audioonly'}));

            data.dispatcher.guildID = data.guildID;

            data.queue.shift();

            data.dispatcher.once('end', function() {

                let commandFile2 = require('./stop.js');

                if (data.queue[0].url) {

                    play(client, ops, data, connection, message)

                } else {

                    commandFile2.run(client, message, args, ops)

                }

        })
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message

Comment: What trouble are you having? What is your expected behaviour for your code, and what is happening instead?

Comment: its too long to send in this comment thatswhy I send a screenshot. http://prntscr.com/pyomnb

Comment: @mypetlion when I try to play a song or a I get this error I could send you my index.js and/or my other files for the music bot.

Comment: hello? anyone here?

Comment: I dont want to hurry or something but .-.

Comment: I'm kinda sad I cant get it by myself